# Advanced Custom Fields - Icon (Image Post Type) src not outputting correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields on my WordPress website and I'm having an issue with certain fields of image post types.

They are outputting like this:

```
<img src="57584, 57584, icon-star-green, icon-star-green.svg, 585, http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/icon-star-green.svg, http://example.com/services/script-writing/icon-star-green/, , 1, , , icon-star-green, inherit, 58344, 2017-10-11 21:15:32, 2018-11-04 01:53:57, 0, image/svg+xml, image, svg+xml, http://example.com/wp-includes/images/media/default.png, 0, 0, Array" class="bens-item__icon" alt="">
```

I have tried deleting and recreating the custom fields as well as reuploading the icon images with the same result. I've also double checked the slug names and everything looks ok.

Here's how the code calls this custom field:

```
<img src="<?php the_field('industry_advantage1_icon'); ?>" class="bens-item__icon" alt="" />
```

Any idea why it would output like this? How can I resolve it?

Comment: can you show how you setup this field? either via code or acf page

Comment: did you forget to echo? <?php echo the_field('industry_advantage1_icon'); ?> and can you post the complete code

Comment: @PavanKumar I dont believe echo is required. the other fields work ok without it. Is that necessary for when youre outputting an image?

Comment: @cpcdev i think echo is required to print the value in img src just give it a try and please get back to me with the answer. i need to know

Comment: You are returning the field as an array. Return the src instead, or use the src in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acf field is returning an array. So to get the url of the image, assign the field to a variable first like so:

```
$image = get_field('industry_advantage1_icon');
```

then you can call the values like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>" class="bens-item__icon" alt="" />
```

Here is the documentation on how to use the Advanced Custom Fields Image field. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
//if custom field isn't blank
if ($alternative_post_image !== '' ) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $alternative_post_image; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
<?php
//show featured image
the_post_thumbnail();
?>
<?php } ?>
```